# Alternative way to fade the background color into another color

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2

in my touches began method i put this simple line of code which fades the background color to red.

```
 runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 1.0))
```

everything is working fine, but the problem is that the code doesn't do anything using ios 7. I was wondering if there is an alternative way to make the background fade into a different color, or if there's an ios 7 version of this code.

Comment: The `colorizeWithColor` `SKAction` is available in iOS 7. Are you testing on a device or the simulator?

Comment: I came up with an over-engineered solution to this problem a while ago... See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21686221/2976878

Comment: Thanks, and i was testing it on a device with ios 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to transition from one color to another. One of the most straightforward approaches is to linearly interpolate between the two colors by combining a progressively larger fraction of the starting color's RGB components with a progressively smaller fraction of the ending color's RBG components over time:

```
red = starting_red * (1.0 - fraction) + ending_red * fraction
green = starting_green * (1.0 - fraction) + ending_green* fraction
blue = starting_blue * (1.0 - fraction) + ending_blue * fraction
```

where `fraction` starts at 0 and ends at 1 in increments of

```
fraction += delta_time * step_size
```

One way to implement this approach is to add code to the `didMoveToView` method of `GameScene`. However, if your game contains multiple scenes, a better strategy is to extend `SKAction` to add a class method that creates a custom action, so it can be used by all scenes.

First, define a structure to store the starting and ending RGB color components. Add this outside of the definition of `GameScene`.

```
struct ColorComponents {
    var red:CGFloat
    var green:CGFloat
    var blue:CGFloat

    init(color:SKColor) {
        self.init()
        var alpha:CGFloat = 0
        color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
    }

    init() {
        red = 0
        green = 0
        blue = 0
    }
}
```

Then, extend `SKAction` by adding the following method that changes the background color to another color. Note that extensions must be defined outside of a class.

```
extension SKAction {
    static func changeColor(startColor:SKColor, endColor:SKColor, duration:NSTimeInterval) -> SKAction {
        // Extract and store starting and ending colors' RGB components
        let start = ColorComponents(color: startColor)
        let end = ColorComponents(color: endColor)
        // Compute the step size
        let stepSize = CGFloat(1/duration)
        // Define a custom class to gradually change a scene's background color
        let change = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(duration) {
            node, time in
            let fraction = time * stepSize
            let red = start.red * (1.0 - fraction) + end.red * fraction
            let green = start.green * (1.0 - fraction) + end.green * fraction
            let blue = start.blue * (1.0 - fraction) + end.blue * fraction
            if let scene = node as? SKScene {
                scene.backgroundColor = SKColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
            }
        }
        return change
    }
}
```

Lastly, create and run an `SKAction`

```
runAction(SKAction.changeColor(backgroundColor, endColor: SKColor.blueColor(), duration: 5))
```

Add this to `didMoveToView` in your `SKScene` subclasses, such as `GameScene`.